# Library management system in php and mysql. how to store barcode in mysql

Tags: php

I have an requirement for library management system. In that i need  bar code access for each entry of book. I don't have any idea about how to store that barcode acess in mysql.

Comment: Barcode is *efficiently* stored as a number.

Comment: ok thanks, i want to know how to read that code in php and mysql.while i checkout how do i recheck with the same barcode. can you  give me any reference link.

Comment: Do you have a barcode scanner?

Comment: yes  i have that, usually when we purchase any product in store,they will stick  that  label on product purchased. like that type, here we are implementing on book.

Comment: not yet started, just i have downloaded some library management system in php and mysql. i am wondering how to  make the barcode check and renew in db. but i can able to write code

Answer (score 0):

when you use barcode scanner, it will type the scanned code(alpha and numeric) in any focused textbox, text area, word processing or any object in you computer that accepts numbers and letters.

lets say you have a barcode reader. And you have an active and focused TEXTBOX on your website. when you scan a barcode using a barcode reader/scanner, u will notice that it will automatically type the code in the TEXTBOX :)

- thats how barcode works.

now to save the barcode, all u have to do is save the alphanumeric code in your database; its plain text :)

Comment: Thank you. how do i check and recheck the book while entering and renew the book. i know how to send the value to database in mysql. i want to know to check and recheck that in mysql.  can you give sample code. i have not yet started the project, just i am gathering information. kindly help me

Comment: no, i cannot give u code. You can Start researching about AJAX/Javascript. u can add |textchanged" event (i think) on the event of the textbox and create a function that will check on the database. That Function will be called when the event "textchanged" triggers.

Comment: ohh by the way, im thinking this is a web app, so im suggesting AJAX/javascript :D i hope my instinct is right ahahha

Comment: yes you are right, this is wep application using php and mysql.from your answer i understood. i want to use trigger in mysql. for reading that bar code entry and renew. function like onchange,onkeyup. before that when you scan a barcode reader, u will notice that it will automatically type the code in the notepad, my question i want to read that notepad file. and send to db. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: the notepad thingy is just my example XD let me change my example above

Comment: i got little idea. now my question is Bar code scanners work just like a keyboard, they input the digits scanned.how do i read the scanning data file from saved location? and i want to know which format did the file  store in computer?

Comment: how do i read the scanning data file from saved location?what i have to do for that.